# Setting up database connection using Vapor framework

Tags: swift, sqlite, vapor

I'm trying to build APIs using Swift and I've chosen to use Vapor.

I've created a SQLite database and am able to connect to it using a DB client.

Now I want my Swift Vapor project to connect to it as well using the FluentSQLite package.

I've created my database in the root folder of my project:

`/Users/rutgerhuijsmans/Documents/runk-3.0`

My database is called `runk-3.0-database`

The folder looks like this:

[image]

I try to connect to my DB using the following configuration:

```
import FluentSQLite
import Vapor

/// Called before your application initializes.
public func configure(_ config: inout Config, _ env: inout Environment, _ services: inout Services) throws {
    /// Register providers first
    try services.register(FluentSQLiteProvider())

    /// Register routes to the router
    let router = EngineRouter.default()
    try routes(router)
    services.register(router, as: Router.self)

    /// Register middleware
    var middlewares = MiddlewareConfig() // Create _empty_ middleware config
    /// middlewares.use(FileMiddleware.self) // Serves files from `Public/` directory
    middlewares.use(ErrorMiddleware.self) // Catches errors and converts to HTTP response
    services.register(middlewares)

    let sqlite: SQLiteDatabase?
    do {
        sqlite = try SQLiteDatabase(storage: .file(path: "runk-3.0-database"))
        print("data base connected") // This gets printed

        /// Register the configured SQLite database to the database config.
        var databases = DatabasesConfig()
        databases.add(database: sqlite!, as: .sqlite)
        services.register(databases)

        /// Configure migrations
        var migrations = MigrationConfig()
        migrations.add(model: User.self, database: .sqlite)
        services.register(migrations)
    } catch {
        print("couldn't connect") // This doesn't get printed
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As IMike17 explained, your code just creates the new DB file into the Build/Products/Debug or release folder. You have to set full path dynamically as below:

```
do {
let directory = DirectoryConfig.detect()
let filePath = directory.workDir + "runk-3.0-database"
sqlite = try SQLiteDatabase(storage: .file(path: filePath)) 
......
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the .file(path: "runk-3.0-database") the method, if you specify only the name, creates a database file with the specified name in the Derived Data folder. If the file exists in the Derived Data folder, SQLiteDatabase uses it. So the DB is erased when cleaning the build folder.

The console prints out the path of the Derived Data where you can find the DB:

`Running default command: /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SQLiteDB-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug/`

If you use a full path to the DB in your project then the file is used.
Change your init method as follows and you should be good to go for a local environment:

`sqlite = try SQLiteDatabase(storage: .file(path: "/Users/rutgerhuijsmans/Documents/runk-3.0/runk-3.0-database"))`